# How to create(compile) DIST folder of a installed library from github

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic3

I am trying to install a `npm` library directly from their github repo. The library is this:

```
https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader
```

My Problem is that when I install directly the library with:

```
npm install --save git+https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader
```

The `node_modules` folder is created but the `DIST` folder not. If I install directly from `npm` with:

```
npm install --save ionic-image-loader
```

The `DIST` folder is created correctly. I have already tried to execute on the root folder of the ionic project the command:

```
npm run build
```

But the `DIST` folder is not created.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: npm build prod should give you Dist folder =)

Comment: what is 'prod'?

Comment: if 'prod' is the path to the package.json of the library, for example `npm build node_modules/ionic-image-loader`this command executes but not create the DIST folder

Comment: have you found any way to solve this?